# Highest depth ever achieved

Tags: engines, stockfish, records, depth

I saw a guy that went into depth 70 with no search moves at 41, 192, 897, 168, and 184 nodes from the starting position on Stockfish a few years ago.
I would like to know if this is still a record or if someone has achieved a higher depth/nodes with Stockfish or equivalent in the start position?

Comment: I don't know the longest achieved, but there is this post on talkchess: http://talkchess.com/forum3/viewtopic.php?t=39741 about the longest puzzle to a mate with best play. The engine apparently solved it with a depth of 271 moves.

Comment: @GertjanBrouwer OP refers to searches _from the starting position_.

Comment: Don't compare depth. Depth is a mostly meaningless number that isn't consistent between engines or versions of an engine. Use nodes instead.

Comment: You could easily write an engine that only looks at one move in each position, thereby achieving depth 71 in just 71 nodes, i.e. almost instantly. Would this engine be any good? No, absolutely not. Yet it can reach this large a depth. That will lead you to Oscar's realization that depth as an absolute number is pretty much meaningless.

Comment: I got a depth of 61 (im a beginner, so wow)